# Script create tar of a Parent directory which will have individual tar's of its sub directories

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I want to write a script which will take two parameters
1. Name of Parent directory (ex. mainFolder)
2. The name of the tar to be created

The parent directory will have subfolers (folder1,folder2,folder3 etc).
I need a script which will create "mainFolder.tar" which will consists of "folder1.tar","folder2.tar","folder3.tar" ...etc...

```
tar cvf mainFolder.jar mainFolder
```

this will create tar of parent directly "mainFolder" only...Can anybody tell me how can I make mainFolder.tar to create & contain tar's of its sub directories...Need a Shell Script (ex. createTar.sh)which will do it..

while creating tar, only "directories" inside the parent folder "mainFolder" should be considered for tar..and not ".txt " files..

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect the directory clause you pointed out. Hopefully it suffices for your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a POSIX compliant solution for your problem. There may be a simpler way (not using any temporary files) but it would involve special and likely non-portable arguments to `tar`.

```
#!/bin/sh


startdir="$(pwd)"

mkdir -p parent/horse/frog parent/dog/frog parent/fish/frog

mkdir newparent

(
    cd parent

    for i in *
    do if [ -d "$i" ] 
       then tar -cf "$startdir/newparent/${i}.tar" ${i}
       fi
       if [ -f "$i" ] 
       then cp "$i" "$startdir/newparent/"
       fi
    done
)

tar -cf newparent.tar newparent
```

Comment: how to exclude some times of file like "*.txt" or "*.confg"....in short how can i make it work only for the directories ?

Comment: Edited so that only directories are archived.

Comment: one more requirement is, the files other than directories should be just copied into the final archive.